# Static variable resets - PHP

Tags: php, variables, static

For some reason my `static` variable resets and I am not sure why it resets.

```
public static $_pwdAdjId = 0; //static variable

function ...() {
// Piece of code that manipulates the static variable
if(isset($_POST['adj'])) {
    self::$_pwdAdjId = $_POST['adj'];
} else if(!isset($_POST['adj']) && $_GET['ajax'] !== 'assignTable') {
    self::$_pwdAdjId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
}
$adj = self::$_pwdAdjId;
...
}
```

When the function is first called, this will be called:

self::$_pwdAdjId = Yii::app()->user->getId();

and saves the value into `$adj` and it works fine.

When the user changes the page the value that is stored into `$adj` is 0 - the initial value of the `static` variable. I am not sure why it is reseting to its initial value instead of the new value stored.

Before First Call:

`self::$_pwdAdjId == 0`

First Call:

`self::$_pwdAdjId == 7`

`$adj == 7`

Page (ajax call): Second Call:

`self::$_pwdAdjId == 0 // supposed to be 7`

Am I missing something? Does the fact that it's called via ajax the second time affect its `static`-ness?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting the static variables to keep their values after the request is served, or did i misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the user changes the page, it's a totally different HTTP request and your program runs again from scratch. `static` does not do what you think it does. You can achieve the result you want using [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Since it looks like you are using Yii framework, you might want to use [its own wrapper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession) over PHP sessions instead of rolling your own (by the way, it also has [wrappers](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getRequest-detail) for getting [HTTP request parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail)).